# Python3 remove newline character from json response

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using the urllib to load a url request and then I load the response to json. This works perfectly but when I change the date range one field contains the \n character and is breaking the line.

How would I stop this from happening I have tried replace and rstrip but can't seem to get them to work.

Here is my code that extracts the data:

```
req = urllib.request.Request("http://example.com/file.json")

r = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
#r = r.rstrip('\n')
content = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))
#content.replace('\n','') - fails due to incorrect type
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "when I change the date range", and who is producing this json ? (if it's you then fix the problem at the source instead, if it's not you and the json is invalid then contact the site's admins/maintainer and ask them to fix it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to call `.replace` on a dictionary. You should call `.replace` on the string:

```
content = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', ''))
```

However, keep in mind that this may invalidate the string as json, depending on its content.

BTW, if you use `requests` you can get `json` directly:

```
import requests

content = requests.get("http://example.com/file.json").json()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to add the .replace it ran but didn't remove the \n

Answer (score 0):

[`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts an argument `indents` which will indent each line in the JSON. Setting the argument to `None` removes new line breaks.

You can try:

```py
json.dumps(indents=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the python String method

```
json.loads(str(r,”utf-8”))
```

To replace string only

```
New_str = str(r,”utf-8”)
```

Comment: Hi I change the following: content = json.loads(str(r,'utf-8')) and added cont.replace('\n','')
When I ran the code I got an error saying replace could not be preformed on a dict

Comment: I think after executed json.loads it will convert the response to dict format that’s why it can not replace because replace is a string function.

Comment: Hi, I'm not having any luck with the solution provided.